# Short solution to find indexes

Tags: arrays, swift

Function is filtered indexes of equal years in one array from another.

I'm looking for shorter solution of my code:

```
 let years = (2015...2025).map { $0 }
 var chosenYears = [2015, 2019, 2016] (example)
```

This function does what i want, but i'm looking for something (more `functional-programming` look).

```
 func selectChoseYears() {
    for (index, year) in years.enumerated() {
        for chosenYear in chosenYears {
            if year == chosenYear { view?.selectCell(at: index) }
        }
    }
 }
```

I tried some solutions, but they look ugly and longer than this.

**Thank you.**

Comment: Looking for "shorter" in programming is the first mistake. You should always look for "more readable" or "simpler", not "shorter".

Comment: @Sulthan is right. You should consider "efficiency" too when it comes to collections and enumerations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possible solutions, for example:

```
let yearIndices = chosenYears.compactMap { years.index(of: $0) }
for yearIndex in yearIndices {
   view?.selectCell(at: yearIndex)
}
```

or just

```
for (index, year) in years.enumerated() where chosenYears.contains(year) {
    view?.selectCell(at: index)
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks!

Comment: In addition, one might consider to make `chosenYears` a `Set`  instead of an array. That would make the  second solution here even more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the `indices` directly

```
years.indices.filter{ chosenYears.contains(years[$0]) }.forEach { view?.selectCell(at: $0) }
```

I totally agree with Sulthan's comment. However I would replace *more readable* and *simpler* with ***more efficient***

Comment: Thanks. I like this solution as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can find indexes of any `Equatable` elements with the following function

### - General index finder

```
func indexes<T: Equatable>(of chosen: [T], in all: [T]) -> [Int] {
    return all.enumerated().filter { chosen.contains($0.element) }.map { $0.offset }
}
```

### - Usage:

```
indexes(of: chosenYears, in: years)
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need `Comparable`?

Comment: `contains()` needs to compare elements. But you are right again. Edited with a better choice. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
let result = (2015...2025).map { $0 }.filter { [2015, 2019, 2016].contains($0)}
```

Comment: That doesn't even compile... Did you mean `[2015,2019,2016].contains($0)`? Btw there's no need to call `map` on a `Range` to convert it to an `Array`, `Array(2015...2025)` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
self.tableView.visibleCells
.flatMap { $0 as? MyCell }
.forEach { $0.updateView(isSelected: chosenYears.contains($0.viewModel?.year) }
```

Although it requires that the cells store view model with the year it represents and you need to implement updateView(isSelected:)